# Extract dates from HTML week picker

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get the days/dates of the selected week of a html week picker (in vanilla JS). For example

```
<input type="week" name="week" id="copyWeekInput">
```

and then

```
document.querySelector("#copyWeekInput")... // for week 18, return something like ["2020-04-27", "2020-04-28", "2020-04-29", "2020-04-30", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-03"]
```

It's strange that they're there in the UI, but I can't find them in the input week's object.

Thanks.

Comment: [`input type="week"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/week) is meant to provide you with just that, a week, not a list of dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `<input type="week" />` is only an input of a week it will not return a date range. You can, however, parse it and find the list yourself.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.onclick = () => {
  let week = document.querySelector('#week');
  let dates = parseDates(week.value);
  console.log(dates);
}


let parseDates = (inp) => {
  let year = parseInt(inp.slice(0,4), 10);
  let week = parseInt(inp.slice(6), 10);

  let day = (1 + (week - 1) * 7); // 1st of January + 7 days for each week

  let dayOffset = new Date(year, 0, 1).getDay(); // we need to know at what day of the week the year start

  dayOffset--;  // depending on what day you want the week to start increment or decrement this value. This should make the week start on a monday

  let days = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) // do this 7 times, once for every day
    days.push(new Date(year, 0, day - dayOffset + i)); // add a new Date object to the array with an offset of i days relative to the first day of the week
  return days;
}
```

```html
<input type="week" id="week" placeholder="<year>-W<week>" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="click" />
```

Comment: Oh, that's neat. My version was much more convoluted. Which part of this sets the start of the week, ie Sun/Mon?

Comment: I noticed it was a day ahead for me, if I pick this week, for example. It was correct for last year though. Perhaps it's a leap year issue?

Comment: @LeonForte I'll add some comments to explain it

Comment: @LeonForte my bad, it assumed all years start on a monday

Comment: Hey, thanks. That's perfect :) 
It works fine when I test locally, but for some reason it's wrong when I click Run code snippet here (maybe SO runs it on their servers and they force Sunday as beginnign of the week). 
Also, when I run `.toISOString().slice(0, 10)`, on the result, it subtracts one day :D Not to worry though, I can manually convert the result to a YYYY-MM-DD format instead.

Comment: I had the same thing, but when I check the console it does log the correct date, even on SO

Comment: why you do declare you function as a variable that is an arrow function?

Comment: @Zaffer arrow unctions are bound by the scope whereas `function parseDates()` would be globally accessible. If `parseDates` were to be used in other places it should be moved to some kind of global function declarations file.